Is there a way to retrieve translation for only one field?
We can retrieve object translation using
sf project retrieve start -m "CustomObjectTranslation:Custom_Object__c-de"

But what if I want to retrieve translation only for particular fields, can this be achieved with cli or Metadata API ?
